# while installing tensorflow-datasets in anaconda; packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow-datasets

while installing tensorflow-datasets in anaconda, using CMD.exe Prompt of anaconda navigator, I am getting the message: packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-datasets
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

environment location: C:\Users\PRASHIK\anaconda3\envs\python_3_6_added / updated specs:tensorflow-datasets


The following packages will be downloaded:

package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
ca-certificates-2020.10.14 |                0         159 KB  anaconda
certifi-2020.6.20          |           py36_0         160 KB  anaconda
dill-0.3.2                 |             py_0          65 KB  anaconda
future-0.18.2              |           py36_1         744 KB  anaconda
googleapis-common-protos-1.52.0|   py36h21ff451_0          75 KB  anaconda
promise-2.3                |           py36_0          37 KB  anaconda
tensorflow-datasets-1.2.0  |           py36_0         2.3 MB  anaconda
tensorflow-metadata-0.14.0 |     pyhe6710b0_1         165 KB  anaconda
tqdm-4.50.2                |             py_0          55 KB  anaconda
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:         3.7 MB

 The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

 dill               anaconda/noarch::dill-0.3.2-py_0
 future             anaconda/win-64::future-0.18.2-py36_1
 googleapis-common~ anaconda/win-64::googleapis-common-protos-1.52.0-py36h21ff451_0
 promise            anaconda/win-64::promise-2.3-py36_0
 tensorflow-datase~ anaconda/win-64::tensorflow-datasets-1.2.0-py36_0
 tensorflow-metada~ anaconda/noarch::tensorflow-metadata-0.14.0-pyhe6710b0_1
 tqdm               anaconda/noarch::tqdm-4.50.2-py_0

 The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

 ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates2021.4.13-~-->anaconda::cacertificates2020.10.14-0
 certifi            pkgs/main::certifi-2020.12.5-py36haa9~ --> anaconda::certifi-2020.6.20py36_0


 Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Is this ok?
Does it causes any issue in future, if yes can someone suggest remedies, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this ok? Does it causes any issue in future, if yes can someone
> suggest remedies, please.

It doesn't cause any issue. By default, conda prefers packages from a higher priority channel over any version from a lower priority channel. Therefore, you can now safely put channels at the bottom of your channel list to provide additional packages that are not in the default channels and still be confident that these channels will not override the core package set.

Conda collects all of the packages with the same name across all listed channels and processes them as follows:

1. Sorts packages from highest to lowest channel priority.
2. Sorts tied packages---packages with the same channel priority---from highest to lowest version number.
3. Sorts still-tied packages---packages with the same channel priority and same version---from highest to lowest build number.
4. Installs the first package on the sorted list that satisfies the installation specifications.

You can refer for a list of all the versions that are available for [ca-certificates](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/ca-certificates/files) and [certifi](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/certifi/files).

For more information on manage channels you can refer [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html)